# import tensorflow broken windows

Tags: python, python-3.x, tensorflow

I had a 32bit python installed, and wanted to use tensorflow. The uninstalling and reinstalling seemed to have broken something. I forced a re-install of tensorflow successfully

```
pip install --upgrade --force-reinstall tensorflow
```

My python version I believe is compatable

```
C:\Python3>python -VV
Python 3.8.6 (tags/v3.8.6:db45529, Sep 23 2020, 15:52:53) [MSC v.1927 64 bit (AMD64)]
```

but running a script that just imports tensorflow gives me errors

```
C:\Python3>python "tf demo.py"
2020-12-06 14:30:51.578969: W tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:59] Could not load dynamic library 'cudart64_101.dll'; dlerror: cudart64_101.dll not found
2020-12-06 14:30:51.579096: I tensorflow/stream_executor/cuda/cudart_stub.cc:29] Ignore above cudart dlerror if you do not have a GPU set up on your machine.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "tf demo.py", line 2, in <module>
    import tensorflow
  File "C:\Users\tim\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python38\site-packages\tensorflow\__init__.py", line 41, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python.tools import module_util as _module_util
  File "C:\Users\tim\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python38\site-packages\tensorflow\python\__init__.py", line 47, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python import keras
  File "C:\Users\tim\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python38\site-packages\tensorflow\python\keras\__init__.py", line 27, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python.keras import models
  File "C:\Users\tim\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python38\site-packages\tensorflow\python\keras\models.py", line 26, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python.keras.engine import functional
  File "C:\Users\tim\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python38\site-packages\tensorflow\python\keras\engine\functional.py", line 38, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python.keras.engine import training as training_lib
  File "C:\Users\tim\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python38\site-packages\tensorflow\python\keras\engine\training.py", line 50, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python.keras.engine import data_adapter
  File "C:\Users\tim\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python38\site-packages\tensorflow\python\keras\engine\data_adapter.py", line 56, in <module>
    from scipy import sparse as scipy_sparse  # pylint: disable=g-import-not-at-top
  File "C:\Users\tim\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python38\site-packages\scipy\__init__.py", line 106, in <module>
    from . import _distributor_init
  File "C:\Users\tim\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python38\site-packages\scipy\_distributor_init.py", line 26, in <module>
    WinDLL(os.path.abspath(filename))
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Python38-64\lib\ctypes\__init__.py", line 373, in __init__
    self._handle = _dlopen(self._name, mode)
OSError: [WinError 193] %1 is not a valid Win32 application
```

Thank you

Comment: The Python version you report is 64-bit, not 32-bit. That is what `[MSC v.1927 64 bit (AMD64)]` means. The message *not a valid Win32 application* in this case almost certainly indicates a bitness mismatch between the version of the interpreter and the version of `tensorflow` you have installed. A 64-bit Python interpreter cannot load 32-bit DLLs, and vice versa. You may still have a 32-bit Python interpreter on your system. Try and find it and see if using that makes the problem go away.

Comment: Thank you, it should be helpful. Sorry wasn't clear enough -  I *HAD* a 32-bit Python, but uninstalled and then installed a 64 bit Python, which is why I posted the version. You are saying I may have another 32 bit version, which may be true.

Comment: No, I thought you might have had 2 side by side. If you have moved to 64 bit Python, for imported modules not in the standard library, you will need to reinstall any that have underlying DLLs. Which may not always be easy to determine, because a pure Python package may have binary dependencies.